# custom Function in Access is returning #Error within a query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I'm joining two tables together. I want to pick one column when their is no data in the other column.  One of the feilds is "SumOfHourlykWh" from qdRevenueConsolidatedByHE and the other is "SumOfAverage" from adSCADAConsolidatedByHE.

The function in the new field is: `kWh: kWhHE([SumOfHourlykWh],[SumOfAverage])`

My VBA code is:

```
Public Function kWhHE(dRevkWh As Double, dSCADAkWh As Double) As Double

If dRevkWh = "" Then
    kWhHE = dRevkWh
Else
    kWhHE = dSCADAkWh
End If

End Function
```

Why is putting #Error in the field KWh?

Comment: I'm confused about your intention for the function because `If dRevkWh = "" Then
    kWhHE = dRevkWh` will attempt to assign an empty string as the function's return value, but the return value is declared `As Double`.  Something is wrong there.

Answer (score 2):

If either [SumOfHourlykWh] or [SumOfAverage] is Null when you call the function in your query ...

```sql
kWhHE([SumOfHourlykWh],[SumOfAverage])
```

... it will trigger an error condition because the function has declared Double for both its arguments.  Null is not Double type; and Double variable can not accept Null.

You could avoid that problem by using `Nz` to substitute another value when the field is Null.  If zero is a reasonable substitute for both fields ...

```sql
kWhHE(Nz([SumOfHourlykWh], 0), Nz([SumOfAverage], 0))
```

Alternatively, you could change the function's argument data types from Double to Variant.  The function would then accept Null.  However you would also then need to revise the function to handle Nulls correctly and to cope with other data types such as String for the function parameters.